# Consulta Linq con multiples Join, Include y con filtros

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-6

llevo algunos días intentando realizar esta consulta, pero voy a tener que recurrir a solicitar ayuda debido a mi falta de experiencia y conocimiento en este tema.

Primero que todo dejo Imagen de las tablas y sus relaciones

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy intentando hacer una consulta que filtre por PRACCARTOL.ANOACAD y PRACCARTOL.SEMACAD y además por NOTACARTOL.NUMRUTAL

si bien, hacer un join entre esto no es difícil, la necesidad que tengo es intentar hacer un INCLUDE de NOTACARTOL a un join como este.

Necesito que por cada registro de ese join, incluyera n objetos que estén en NOTACARTOL por un NUMRUTAL especifico.

```
var Ejemplo = db.PRACCARTOL
            .Join(db.CARTOLA,
                    PRC => PRC.KEYPROGACA,
                    C => C.KEYPROGACA,
                    (PRC, C) =>
                    new
                    {
                        ANOACAD = PRC.ANOACAD,
                        SEMACAD = PRC.SEMACAD,
                        KEYCARTOL = C.KEYCARTOLA,
                        KEYESTADOCARTOL = C.KEYESTCART
                    }
             )
            .Join(db.PLANCARTOL,
                    PRC => PRC.KEYCARTOL,
                    C => C.KEYCARTOLA,
                    (PRC, C) =>
                    new
                    {
                        ANOACAD = PRC.ANOACAD,
                        SEMACAD = PRC.SEMACAD,
                        KEYCARTOL = C.KEYCARTOLA,
                        KEYPLANIFI = C.KEYPLANIFI
                    }
             )
            .Where(PRCc => PRCc.ANOACAD == agno)
            .Where(PRCc => PRCc.SEMACAD == semestre);
```

He intentado con múltiples includes, pero el drama es que no me deja hacer el filtro por NUMRUTAL y aquí es donde ya se escapa de mi conocimiento.

Una búsqueda inversa no me sirve (dejo ejemplo)

```
            var Ejemplo = await db.NOTACARTOL
            .Include(PLC => PLC.PLANCARTOL)
            .Where(x => x.NUMRUTAL == rut)
            .ToListAsync();
```

ya que tendría demasiada información innecesaria en la respuesta (me repetiría n veces la información de PLANCARTOL siendo que con una me bastaría)

Algo como esto seria ideal para mi

```
[
    {
    "ANOACAD": 20,
    "SEMACAD": 1,
    "KEYCARTOL": 24057,
    "KEYPLANIFI": 151796
    "NOTACARTOL":[
        {
        NUMRUTAL: 12345
        NOTANUM: 6
        },
        {
        NUMRUTAL: 12345
        NOTANUM: 5
        }
    ]

    },
    {
    "ANOACAD": 20,
    "SEMACAD": 1,
    "KEYCARTOL": 24058,
    "KEYPLANIFI": 151234
    "NOTACARTOL":[
        {
        NUMRUTAL: 12345
        NOTANUM: 4
        },
        {
        NUMRUTAL: 12345
        NOTANUM: 7
        }
    ]

    }
]
```

Agradecería orientación o saber si lo que necesito es factible de realizar o no de esta forma, sino para buscar otra que me permita realizar eso :)

Comment: Te recomiendo fuertemente hacer un sp y llamar a ese sp desde C#. Mejorará el rendimiento de tu aplicación al quitarle lógica compleja de datos.

Comment: De hecho, para mi es mucho mas fácil de esa forma que mencionas, pero con un SP como podría obtener un objeto parecido al de ejemplo?, he visto que SQL SERVER 2016 permite crear respuestas JSON directo desde la base de datos, lamentablemente contamos con SQL 2014

Comment: Yo crearia un SP normal, sin salidas especiales... Y en mi back, construiria una clase con la estructura de salida de mi sp y despues simplemente le pasas parámetros (si es que necesita) y recibes la info.

Answer (score 0):

@Oscar.

La respuesta corta sería que no te preocupes por ir encadenando operación tras operación. Eso no va a afectar al tráfico real de la base de datos a tu servicio.

*Linq* es un sistema basado en *commands tree*, o árbol de comandos. Esto significa que *Linq* va encadenando las operaciones (`Where`, `Include`, `GroupBy`, `ThenInclude`, ...) a una *query*, pero ésta no se ejecuta operación tras operación, sinó que se ejecuta una vez se itera sobre los datos "virtualmente" filtrados por dicha *query*. A esto le llaman la *deferred execution*, o ejecución diferida.

La integración de *Linq* con *Entity Framework* eleva este concepto a las bases de datos.

```
// _context es el DbContext de Entity Framework
var query = _context.SomeTable
                    .Where(t => t.Id == id)
                    .GroupBy<Field>(t => t.Field)
                    .Include<Inner>(t => t.Inner)
                    .ThenInclude<InnerInner>(i => i.Inner);
```

Ejecutar el código de arriba no va ejecutar ninguna query a la base de datos en absoluto. Sólo se está construyendo una *query* que se ejecutará una vez recorramos los resultados de ésta, y sólo entonces.

```
var results = await query.ToListAsync();
// En este punto se hace la consula a la base de datos
// Y esperamos (await) a la respuesta.
```

*Entity Framework* agrega una capa a *Linq* para montar una sentencia SQL a partir de la *query* de *Linq* dependiendo del *provider* asignado al contexto de la base de datos. Eso es lo que configuramos cuando llamamos a los métodos del tipo `UseSqlServer`, `UseMySql`, `UseOracleProvider`, ...

Cuando digo que hace falta recorrer los resultados es algo literal (y no). Los métodos como `ToList`, `ToArray`, `First`, `Single`, `Any`, `Count`, ... por dentro recorren la colección de resultados. Algunos de ellos la recorren entera, otros no. Si hablásemos de *Linq* nativo tendría relevancia este hecho. Cuando hablamos de *Linq* contra *Entity Framework* no tanto, ya que aunque no vayamos a recorrer toda la colección, la llamada a la base de datos ya se ha efectuado.

```
var predicate = (SomeTable t) => t.Id == id;
var result = await _context.SomeTable
                           .ToListAsync()
                           .Where(predicate);
```

Este caso es el que siempre deberías evitar: ejecutar la llamada a la base de datos y después filtrar (o hacer cualquier otra operaciíon).

Dejo [aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution) la documentación oficial que da todo este tipo de explicaciones de forma mucho más extensa. Lo recomiendo a cualquier que tenga que trabajar con *Linq*, ya sea co *Entity Framework* o no (porque esto se aplica también fuera del contexto de las bases de datos).

Espero que sirva.